# Hibernate mapping ONE-TO-MANY

Tags: java, hibernate

[image: tables]

Здесь только часть таблицы.
Как написать маппинг для такой ситуации? Когда отправитель(`sender`) и получатель (`receiver`) это по сути одна и та же сущность, но при этом записи будут разные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="sender")
private Set<Waybill> senderCompanies;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="receiver")
private Set<Waybill> receiverCompanies;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "waybill")
public class Waybill {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
private ClientCompany sender;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")
private ClientCompany receiver;

...
}
```